# Flutter VLC Player implementation

Tags: flutter, video, vlc

Is there something I am missing setting up the VLC on flutter? Only empty. No player seen just a blank page here is my flutter code, just followed from their documentation. Here is the code. I might miss something. Is there any alternative way to use the VLC plugin? I am new to Flutter. Thank you

````
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late VlcPlayerController _videoPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _videoPlayerController = VlcPlayerController.network(
      'https://local.clift.mdu1.net/3ABN/index.m3u8',
      hwAcc: HwAcc.FULL,
      autoPlay: false,
      options: VlcPlayerOptions(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    await _videoPlayerController.stopRendererScanning();
    await _videoPlayerController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: VlcPlayer(
          controller: _videoPlayerController,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          placeholder: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

try to add setstate in initState, or intime equal vlccontroller to VlcPlayerController.network